# Natural candidates for the hierarchy inside NPI

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

Let's assume that $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$. $\mathsf{NPI}$ is the class of problems in $\mathsf{NP}$ which are neither in $\mathsf{P}$ nor in $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. You can find a list of problems conjectured to be $\mathsf{NPI}$ [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc/).

[Ladner's theorem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/799/generalized-ladners-theorem) tells us that if $\mathsf{NP}\neq\mathsf{P}$ then there is an infinite hierarchy of $\mathsf{NPI}$ problems, i.e. there are $\mathsf{NPI}$ problems which are harder than other $\mathsf{NPI}$ problems.

> I am looking for candidates of such problems, i.e. I am interested in pairs of problems
>   - $A,B \in \mathsf{NP}$,
>   - $A$ and $B$ are conjectured to be $\mathsf{NPI}$,
>   - $A$ is known to reduce to $B$,
>   - but there are no known reductions from $B$ to $A$.

Even better if there are arguments for supporting these, e.g. there are results that $B$ does not reduce to $A$ assuming some conjectures in complexity theory or cryptography.

Are there any *natural* examples of such problems?

Example: Graph Isomorphism problem and Integer Factorization problem are conjectured to be in $\mathsf{NPI}$ and there are argument supporting these conjectures. Are there any decision problems harder than these two but not known to be $\mathsf{NP}$-hard?

Comment: So you are looking for problems $P \in \mathrm{NP}$ such that $P_1 \leq_p P \leq_p P_2$ with $P_1 \in \mathrm{NPI}$ and $P_2 \in \mathrm{NPC}$?

Comment: What do you mean by NPV?

Comment: German teaching coming through, edited.

Comment: Yes but there is no known reduction from P to P1 (similarly no known reduction from P2 to P).

Comment: [Lander's theorem](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/799/generalized-ladners-theorem) implies that there are such languages, but I guess you want natural ones, something like Factoing or GI.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for natural examples.

Comment: technically, factoring is in FNP and not know to be in FP

Comment: there are several problems with a status similar to factoring, see this paper by Papadimitriou http://theory.stanford.edu/~megiddo/pdf/papadimX.pdf

Comment: besides, we have a very nice list in cstheory http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/79/problems-between-p-and-npc/

Comment: why is the list that Marcos links to not the answer to your question ?

Comment: @Suresh take your favoraite problem in the list and give me a harder natural problem which is not known to be NP-hard.

Comment: I see. so you want to know candidate sinks in the (directed) graph of reductions between problems on the list. this sounds like a great REU project for some undergrad :)

Comment: I have taken the liberty of rewording the problem to better emphasize what is being asked (independently of the comments); I hope that this is okay.

Comment: I tried to make the question easier to read, feel free to edit or roll back.

Comment: ps: I think this would also be suitable for cstheory, so if you don't get satisfying answers here feel free to repost it there. (It can't be migrated since more than 60 days has passed.)

Comment: Thanks Kaveh. I will wait until the bounty expires and then post it on cstheory.

Comment: [Copy](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16275/186) on [cstheory.se].

Answer (score 5):

I've found a nice problem called *ModularFactorial*. Take as input two $n$-digit integers $x$ and $y$, and output $x! \mod y$. This problem is at least as hard as *Factoring* and not know to be hard for **FNP**. The reference is the recent (and beautiful) book by Cristopher Moore and Stephan Mertens [The Nature of Computation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199233217), page 79.

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for problems in NP.  Can you reformulate this as a decision problem?

Comment: FNP is the function version (i.e.,search problems) of NP. In fact, factoring is not in NP, it is FNP. For instance, the decision problem for factoring is trivial, the complexity is just O(1), but the search problem is the difficult part. Since the OP gave factoring as an example, I think this is also a valid answer.

Comment: Factoring can be reformulated into a decision problem as follows: given an integer $n$ and an integer $k$, does $n$ contain a factor $d$ with $1 < d \le k$?  Is there an analogous decision version of the ModularFactorial problem?

Comment: @Marcos, Thanks. I'm interested in decision problems in NP.

Comment: @ZachLangley, yes of course I agree, but I was thinking in another decision version, namely, "does x has a factor?". The answer there is just, "yes" always. You can do the same with modularfactorial, give an integer k and decide if $x!\mod y$ is greater than $k$ or not.

Comment: also, $k\in\{0,\dots,y-1\}$ or it just doesn't have any sense.